# What is the speciality of LEA in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I've seen a peice of code like,

```
void makeArray()
{
    char myString[30];
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        myString[i] = '*';
}
```

Turn it into MASM,

```
makeArray PROC
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    sub  esp, 32
    lea  esi, [ebp-30]
    mov  ecx, 30
L1: mov  BYTE PTR [esi], '*'
    inc  esi
    loop L1
    add  esp, 32
    pop  ebp
    ret
makeArray ENDP
```

Question:
Can I write `mov  esi, ebp-30` instead of `lea  esi, [ebp-30]`?
Can I write `mov  esp, ebp` instead of `add  esp, 32`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LEA is a single operation that can combine an addition of up to three operands - a constant, a register, and another register optionally multiplied by a small power of two.

EDIT: LEA has two arguments - a register and an effective address. The effective address can take the following form:

```
[Base + ROffset + RIndex*Scale]
```

Where Base is a constant, ROffset is a register, RIndex is another register (or the same one, that's allowed) and Scale can be 1 (i. e. omitted), 2, 4, or 8. Any addend can be omitted in this expression. For example: `[100+eax]`. Or `[ecx+esi*2]`. Or `[20+eax+eax*8]`. The order of addends doesn't matter; it might help code readability though.

LEA calculates the address and places it into the destination register. The address itself, not what's in that address - it's not a memory access command. But it's a good way to do simple arithmetics in a single command. For example, if RBase and ROffset are the same, you can do multiplication by 3, 5, or 9 cheaply.

> Can I write mov  esi, ebp-30 instead of lea  esi, [ebp-30]?

No, `mov` doesn't support expressions on the right hand side (other than compile-time ones, e. g. 10+20). But you can write

```
mov esi, ebp
sub esi, 30
```

> Can I write mov  esp, ebp instead of add  esp, 32?

In this particular example - yes, you can.

Comment: I'm not very clear about your first sentence(LEA is a... ...power of two), would you please explain it more concretely?

Answer (score -1):

Your first statement is wromg. Brackets are missing, then it would be right, the second assumption is correct.

Comment: You mean I can write it like `mov  esi, [ebp-30]`? I doubt about that because [ebp-30] is the value whose address is ebp-30 while I'm requiring the address(ebp-30).

Comment: You can write that but it won't be equivalent to `lea esi, [ebp-30]`. Instead of address, you'll get the value at that address.